# wierd oddity between JsonConvert.SerializeObject and json.stringify

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm working with a JavaScript client and a c# socket server sending messages back and forth in JSON.

on the server I have a multi-dimensional array like so:

```
MapData[0,0,0] = 1;
MapData[0,0,1] = 2;
```

its dimensions are 900x900x2

in JavaScript if I do `json.stringify(MapData)` I get like this

`[[[1,2],[3,4]]]` etc

but c# `jsonconvert.serializeobject(MapData)` gives me like this:
[1,2,3,4]

can someone explain why the c# serialize and JavaScript stringify are giving different values ?

I tried

```
int[][][] MapData = new int[900][][];
// Zero out the map
for (int variable1 = 0; variable1 <= 899; variable1++) {
    for (int variable2 = 0; variable2 <= 899; variable2++) {
        MapData[variable1][variable2][0] = 0;
    }
}
```

but it throws an unhandled null exception at MapData[variable1][variable2][0] = 0;

Finally figured it out with Jeff's help

```
int[][][] MapData = new int[900][][];
// Zero out the map
for (int a = 0; a < MapData.Length; a++)
{
    MapData[a] = new int[900][];
    for (int b = 0; b < MapData[a].Length; b++)
    {
        MapData[a][b] = new int[2];
        for (int c = 0; c < MapData[a][b].Length; c++)
                MapData[a][b][c] = 0;
    }
}
```

then the JsonConvert.SerializeObject(MapData) works like I want

Thankyou for pointing me in the right direction Jeff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JsonConvert.SerializeObject()` just uses an iterator to get the contents of an array and serialize it.  Multidimensional arrays implement IEnumerable, so that's why you're seeing that behavior.

`JsonConvert.SerializeObject()` will give you the result you expect given a jagged array, ie `MapData[0][0][1]`.

If it's feasible to change your .NET code to use a jagged array, then that's what I'd suggest you do.  If not, you can do on-the-fly conversion before serializing:

```
var jagged =  
    Enumerable.Range(0, MapData.GetLength(0)).Select(
        i => Enumerable.Range(0, MapData.GetLength(1)).Select(
            j => Enumerable.Range(0, MapData.GetLength(2)).Select(
                k => MapData[i,j,k]).ToArray()).ToArray()).ToArray();
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jagged)
```

Comment: but I need to convert the entire array into JSON that the client can understand as it needs to take the JSON and dump it to a matching JavaScript array.

Comment: Then change your array to a jagged array.  Or change it on the fly before serializing, although that's fairly inefficient.

Comment: thankyou for pointing me in the right direction between you and google I got it soted out. now onto the next issue at hand